# run just code from one Rmarkdown document in another Rmarkdown document with duplicate chunk names

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I am writing a series of reports in Rmarkdown that build off each other. I would like to include the results from the previous report in the report I am currently working on. I have seen other questions that suggested using `purl` to extract R code from a Rmarkdown document and then run that, so I tried the following:

````
```{r read.previous, echo=FALSE}
source(knitr::purl("previous.Rmd",output=tempfile(),documentation=0))
```
````

But when I try to knit the current report, it fails, complaining that there are duplicate chunk names. I thought the `documentation=0` argument would remove all chunk names, but it appears that running `purl` inside another `knit` session is getting things all confused. Making all the chunk names unique across reports is impractical in my case.

Is there a simple way to just get the code from an Rmarkdown file and execute inside another, ignoring chunk names?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a chunk of code as follows should resolve your problem:

````
```{r}
options(knitr.duplicate.label = 'allow')
```
````