# With RMarkdown is there a way to use knitr syntax to call external R code from a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, r-markdown, knitr

I am using RMarkdown to write a journal article. For various reasons I'd prefer to have the R analysis script in a separate Jupyter notebook. Is there a nice way to call R code from `MyAnalysis.ipynb` in `MyArticle.Rmd`?

I know I can use `knitr` syntax to have the `.Rmd` file read and execute chunks of R code from a `.R` file [like so](http://zevross.com/blog/2014/07/09/making-use-of-external-r-code-in-knitr-and-r-markdown/). And that you can use `knitr::purl` to call code chunks from one rmarkdown doc in another [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42631398/run-just-code-from-one-rmarkdown-document-in-another-rmarkdown-document-with-dup/).

But I would like to be able to "purl" the code from the `.ipynb` file. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: `.ipynb` is JSON. You can read it via `jsonlite::fromJSON()`, and extract the cells you need from the list.